# How should I report cleaning expenses on airbnb

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, form-1099, eligible-expenses

I am trying to file my U.S. joint tax return for year 2018 and I have a question. My wife was running an Airbnb rental business for which the 1099 was reported to the IRS by Airbnb in the amount of about $40,000. She says she paid total of $7,000 for a cleaning guy over the course of the year. She did not give a 1099 to the guy and she paid cash.

My question is: can we file this as an expense in our tax return even though it is a significant amount for which I have no paper trail?

Comment: $7000 is above the threshold where issuing a 1099 (and filing a copy with the IRS) becomes mandatory

Comment: Can she not go find the guy and get him to give her receipts? Or will that get *him* in trouble with the taxman?

Comment: Some relevant reading for her: https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/reporting-payments-to-independent-contractors

Comment: If a service demands cash and gives no receipt, you *know* that they are cheating on their taxes.  So don't be surprised later, when *you* end up paying *their* taxes.